# Volume of Solid W/ Base Region...

Tags: integration, volume

How would I go about the following?

Find the volume of the solid $W$ whose base is the region enclosed by $y=x^2$ and $y=1$, and the cross-sections perpendicular to the y-axis are squares.

Comment: **hint**: $z=2|x|$ and $V=\int \int \int dx dy dz$

Answer (score 0):

At any position $x$ you have a square of side $1-x^2$. Therefore, you can sum the areas of the squares along $x$. The figure below may help. Thus,

$$V=\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^2~dx=\frac{16}{15}$$

[image]

Comment: Your sections are perpendicular to $X-$axis.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thanks for pointing out my error. I'll just leave this as is, for what it's worth. It does demonstrate a viable method.

Answer (score 0):

For each $y$ fixed $x$ varies from $-\sqrt y$ to $\sqrt y$, so the integral is:
$$
\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y}\int_0^{2\sqrt y}\,dz\,dx\,dy = \cdots
$$